# express-validation throws an error: Error('Please provide a validation schema')

Tags: node.js, validation, express

I am new to Node.js. I wanted to add a simple validation for one of the form's field just to test the validation offered in Express. I followed the steps at https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validation

I used express-validation middleware. I installed the appropriate modules(express-validation and joi).

Then I have added a folder "validation" and file "edit" with the following content:

```
var Joi = require('joi');

module.exports = {
    body: {
        title: Joi.string().required()
    }
};
```

In the route that handles the post from the form I have added the appropriate parameter:

```
router.post('/', validate(validation.edit), function(req, res, next)
```

and saved the middleware and file with validation rule to the vars:

```
var validate = require('express-validation');
var validation = require('../validation/edit.js');
```

When I run the app it throws an error: Error('Please provide a validation schema').

So, I wonder what validation schema is required and where I suppose to add it?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with how you have your require defined. Since there is only one object in your edit.js module.exports, you do not need to call .edit on the validation. You can just do:

```
router.post('/', validate(validation), function(req, res, next)
```

Alternatively, you can define an index.js in your validation directory:

```
exports.edit = require('./edit');
```

Then require it:

```
var validation = require('../validation/');
```

And keep your middleware call the same as you had it. This will allow you to add more validation types easily, with only one require line. The [project's test directory](https://github.com/AndrewKeig/express-validation/tree/master/test) has a good example of this.